# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes immediately after login

Tags: 20.04, login, freeze

It was working normal I was just trying to upgrade python version. Suddenly my computer freezes. I hard shutdown the computer and restarted it again. After login the desktop shows but my mouse freezes and some function key starts to work but some doesn't. Before login everything works fine mouse hovers everywhere keyboard functions properly. When I try to login through wayland it works. I have a lot of important documents please help.

I don't have any dual boot it's purely Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: If you change the default python3 version; you will find many tools that rely on python3 will no longer work; this is more noticeable on desktop systems as many desktop features will no longer function/operate, until the default python3 change has been reverted. Revert your changes & don't change the default python3. For help you'll have to be specific as to what you changed, but text terminals will still function allowing you to explore logs & remind yourself of what you did & thus what needs to be reverted..  Also note `apt` & high-level package tools may no longer function, but `dpkg` will

Comment: I'm working on it I'll get back in a while, thanks @guiverc

Comment: Still doesn't work. I think it's not a problem with python

Comment: You’ve said you have a lot of important documents; this isn’t any kind of solution to your problem, but I’d suggest - before doing anything else - use a live usb session to access your data and back it all up. If you do serious damage to your system (or if it’s already damaged beyond easy repair), it’s then not a major problem to reinstall Ubuntu and transfer your data back.

Comment: Yes, I have backed up all my data. Thank you